# Can an assembly that includes a non-CLS-compliant reference be CLS-compliant?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, cls-compliant

I have an existing DLL that is not CLS-compliant that I reference from my own project. When I mark my assembly as CLS-compliant, I get compiler warnings that names in the referenced assembly are not CLS-compliant.

Is there a way I can keep my assembly CLS-compliant and mark the referenced one as not?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, your DLL can be CLS-compliant as long as it doesn't expose any non-CLS-compliant members from the referenced assembly -- that is, it doesn't mention them in any of its own public or protected members or types.  (It can still use them in private and internal members and types.)

If your DLL does need to expose types directly from the non-compliant DLL, you can either try encapsulating those types in your own wrappers (e.g. a method might return a `MyWrapperAroundNaughtyType` instead of a `NaughtyType`), or you can mark the relevant members of your API `CLSCompliant(false)` to opt just those members out of compiler checking.

Comment: Do I also need to mark "Embed Interop Types" as false? (It's a COM library that's not CLS-compliant due to names with underscores.)

Comment: I am not sure.  Since the interop types you'd be using are public, they'd be embedded as public, which means they'd be checked for CLS-compliance.  But when I did a quick experiment it seemed to go okay -- but perhaps I just got lucky with my COM types.  Perhaps try creating a small dummy assembly that imports the problem COM types and try it on that before embarking on it with your real assembly?

Comment: I just tried it with `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` and get warnings if I include it in a `using` statement anywhere. It seems like either marking my assembly as non-compliant or not embedding the interop types is the way to go. Or I could fully qualify all class names... nah.

Comment: if you wrap around the naughty type, aren't you still exposing it with your wrapper?

Comment: Not as long as you keep any mentions of the naughty type private or internal within the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing because the other suggestions didn't work was setting the property `Embed Interop Types` of the referenced dll (with the non-CLS-compliant members) to false.